# How to validate option parameter value from the struct

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am working on rust-lang facing issue when i am trying do validation on option parameter during the updating. Below is demo version of code. Please do help me. Better to use match pattern or if condition statement.

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct UserUpdateReq {
    uuid: Option<i32>,
    first_name: Option<String>,
    last_name: Option<String>,
}

fn update_user(req: Json) => Result<Response<Vec<i32>>, String>{

   let req: UserUpdateReq = try_s!(json::from_value(req));

   // Here I need to validate optional parameters
   // checking both parameters have a value. In case both are None, return err message
   // if any one value is present update that value.

}
```

Comment: "both parameter"? You have 3 parameters. Do you mean all the parameters? "if any one value is present update that value" Update where? You don't seem to be storing users anywhere, and I don't know what `Response` is supposed to mean or where the `Vec<i32>` is supposed to come from. It's unclear what your question is asking.

Comment: If all 3 members are required why are you wrapping them in an `Option`?

Comment: FYI, unrelated to the question, but a UUID is 128 bit, not 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that at least one of `first_name` and `last_name` are provided, you can do it on a case-by-case basis with:

```
match (req.first_name, req.last_name) {
    (Some(first_name), Some(last_name)) => {
        // update both
    }
    (None, Some(last_name)) => {
        // update last name
    }
    (Some(first_name), None) => {
        // update first name
    }
    (None, None) => {
        // error
    }
```

Or

```
if req.first_name.is_none() && req.last_name.is_none () {
    // error
} else {
    if let Some(first_name) = req.first_name {
        // update first name
    }
    if let Some(last_name) = req.last_name {
        // update last name
    }
}
```